# How to access the file name from the particular location using Listcontrol in MFC?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I am a beginner to Visual Studio C++. I am creating a dialog based application using MFC. I want to read some file and display some required text from that file in the dialog.

the code is:

```
   CFileFind finder;
    bool bFound;

   CString filename = "C:\\FilesLocation\\*.txt";

   bFound = finder.FindFile(filename);
   if(bFound) 
 {

   m_List.AddString(finder.GetFileName());  }

 in the last line,   error appears, whereas m_List is the member variable for List Control/
```

and Clistctrl has no member Addstring.

How to access the file name and display in the dialog ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you're going to achieve, use [CListCtrl::InsertItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b9s12fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) 
or use `CListBox` instead of `CListCtrl`. `CListBox` has `AddString` method.

Comment: i have already been doing ClistCtrl function. I cannot switch to Clistbox now. No knowledge about  CListCtrl::InsertItem

Comment: @Nabeel: I provided the link to MSDN in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
HANDLE WINAPI FindFirstFile(
  __in   LPCTSTR lpFileName,
  __out  LPWIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData
);
```

Where

**pFileName [in]**
     The directory or path, and the file name, which can include wildcard characters, for example, an asterisk (*) or a question mark (?).

**lpFindFileData [out]**
 A pointer to the WIN32_FIND_DATA structure that receives information about a found file or directory.

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(path of the directory,&ffd);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) 
    {
        return;
    } 
    else
    {
                ffd.cFileName;

         }
```